# No lib of ivy cache jars created when I create package or install

Tags: sbt, ivy

I am trying to get a sbt 0.13.12 project (was) to compile and the problem I have is there should be a was/lib directory created that contains the .ivy2/cache files.   While I get all the other expected directories created under target, the cache jars are never collected anywhere.

I have looked through the build.sbt file and I don't see anything that creates a lib directory or a batch script that copies the ivy2 cache jars into a lib directory so I am out of ideas on how to proceed.  The project was using "validator", a COTS tool for sbt which no longer exists.  I can make a script that copies all the jars out and saves them in the lib directory if I have to, but there must have been something that did it before.

The only lines for ivy are in build.sbt file:

```
lazy val userHome = SettingKey[File]("user-home", "The user's home directory: ~", AMinusSetting)
userHome := new _root_.java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"))
externalIvySettings(userHome(_ / "/.ivy2/ivysettings.xml"))
```

in .ivy2 the ivysettings.xml file is this old code to a dead repro.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-settings>
    <settings defaultResolver="main" />
    Authentication required for publishing (deployment). 'Artifactory Realm' is the realm used by Artifactory so don't change it.
    <credentials host="itarArtifactory" realm="Artifactory Realm" username="n/a" passwd="n/a" />
    <resolvers>
    <chain name="main">
      <url name="public" m2compatible="true">
        <artifact pattern="http://itarArtifactory:8081/artifactory/repo/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" />
        <ivy pattern="http://itarArtifactory:8081/artifactory/repo/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).pom" />
      </url>
    </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivy-settings>
```

I am currently commenting out the externalIvySettings line and removed the ivysettings.xml file since its all dead.  On windows 7 PC it was install on in the lab, I see all cache jars were copied into the was/lib directory.   The old development windows box was never saved so all I have is bitbucket and the PC it was installed on.  Everyone that work on this project is long gone.

So any ideas on how the cache jars are bundled into one directory?  If this was maven I could make a goal to bundle the jars, but this is sbt.